# Use MySQL result in another query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code which lists everything in **tbl_inventory** for a given company which works fine:

```
$result_inventory = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_inventory WHERE company_id='$company_id' ORDER BY ip_address")

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_inventory))
echo "<td>{$row['type']} </td>";
echo "<td>{$row['ip_address']} </td>";
echo "<td>{$row['site']} </td>";
```

The **site** column gives a number which correlates to an ID in another table which I want to use to run another query such as:

```
SELECT name FROM tbl_sites WHERE site_id='$site'
```

However I'm not sure on how to define **$site** from the previous result

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: How is it correlating - one to one or many to one?

Comment: A perfect example where you's want to use JOIN operations (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rayblade's answer seems legit, however, you can also perform a `JOIN`-statement between the two tables:

```
SELECT tbl_sites.name FROM tbl_inventory 
LEFT JOIN tbl_sites ON tbl_inventory.site = tbl_sites.site_id 
WHERE tbl_inventory.company_id='$company_id' 
ORDER BY tbl_inventory.ip_address
```

This will successfully get the `tbl_sites.name` column, for every company that matches a site. Here you can of course get any arbitrary number of columns, just make sure to use the table name as prefix, since we now have two tables in the query.

Comment: This did the trick, thanks - I'm new to PHP/SQL and always wondered when I'd need to start using joins

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
$result_inventory = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_inventory WHERE company_id='$company_id' ORDER BY ip_address")

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_inventory)){
  echo "<td>{$row['type']} </td>";
  echo "<td>{$row['ip_address']} </td>";
  $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name FROM tbl_sites WHERE site_id='$row[site]'")
  if ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
    echo "<td>{$row2['name']} </td>";
}
```

but i think it's a so inefficient